# Network Dataset -- can't solve route

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, network-analyst

I've built out numerous network datasets before, so I'm confused as to why I'm getting this error.

I've built out a polyline file for the sidewalks in my community.

Warning: No route from location "Graphic Pick 1" to location "Graphic Pick 2".
Error: No solution found.

I can solve a route on a single line, but not on any route that requires taking multiple lines.

I checked all the options under 'location snap options', but that didn't solve it.

Figuring connectivity might be an issue, I merged the entire file into a single feature, but I still got the same error.

Does anyone have an idea of why it won't link up? Did I need to make sure the polygons only crossed each other on nodes so they intersected?

I don't remember running across this problem before.

Comment: I have found when doing this - to run my appended lines through the FeatureToLine_management().  This will create Nodes at all intersections and allow turning within your Network Dataset analysis.

Comment: @dklassen: Thanks! Worked perfectly. If you put this as an answer, I'll mark it as the accepted answer and close out the question as solved.

Comment: please help !!!!!!!!! i have the same error but not solved by the featureToLine_management :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found when doing this - to run my appended lines through the FeatureToLine_management(). This will create Nodes at all intersections and allow turning within your Network Dataset analysis.